# $\max_{x,y>0}\left(\min\left\{x,\dfrac{1}{y},y+\dfrac{1}{x}\right\}\right)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers, and let $m$ be the minimum value among $x,$ $\frac{1}{y},$ and $y + \frac{1}{x}.$ Find the largest possible value of $m.$

So basically I need to find $$\max_{x,y>0}\left(\min\left\{x,\dfrac{1}{y},y+\dfrac{1}{x}\right\}\right).$$

---

I tried to consider some cases for $x$ and $y$, and doing the problem in each of those cases, but that didn't get me anywhere. Could anyone give me any hints on how to proceed?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just to check, is it $1 + \frac{1}{x}$ or $y + \frac{1}{x}$ (as you wrote once in the body)?

Comment: It is $y+\frac{1}{x}$. Sorry, I made a typo. :(

Comment: Perhaps OP wants $\displaystyle\max_{x,y > 0}\left(\min\left\{x,\tfrac{1}{y},y+\tfrac{1}{x}\right\}\right)$

Comment: @JimmyK4542 that makes more sense to be honest.

Comment: 1) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2176728p16246737   2)https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1644670p10375204 3)https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1789971p11836874